# how get src of audio elemnt from list in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

How can I get the src of an `audio` tag when I click on the button which plays it?

I have many `li` tags, each `li` contains three tags:

1. An `a` tag which takes the source of the track which will be played. => done
2. An `audio` tag which is like the element before; I just use it to take the src and make it ready for get it with the 3 element. => not done yet
3. A `button` tag which gets the src of the `audio` tag it relates to.

When I click on each button, I want the function to return to me the src of the `audio` or `a` tag which corresponds with it within the same `li` tag.

Here is my code:

```html
<ul id="playList">
  <li>
    <a href="audio/track1.mp3">track1</a>
    <audio src="audio/track1.mp3" id="aud"></audio>
    <button onclick="getTrack()">get this track src</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="audio/track2.mp3">track2</a>
    <audio src="audio/track2.mp3" id="aud"></audio>
    <button onclick="getTrack()">get this track src</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="audio/track3.mp3">track3</a>
    <audio src="audio/track3.mp3" id="aud"></audio>
    <button onclick="getTrack()">get this track src</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [**siblings**](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) is what you are looking for. You can use it like the following:

```js
function getTrack(elm){
let $aud = $(elm).siblings( "audio" ).first();
console.log($aud.attr("src"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="playList">
  <li>
    <a href="audio/track1.mp3">track1</a>
    <audio src="audio/track1.mp3" id="aud"></audio>
    <button onclick="getTrack(this)">get this track src</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="audio/track2.mp3">track2</a>
    <audio src="audio/track2.mp3" id="aud"></audio>
    <button onclick="getTrack(this)">get this track src</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="audio/track3.mp3">track3</a>
    <audio src="audio/track3.mp3" id="aud"></audio>
    <button onclick="getTrack(this)">get this track src</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**Edit:** Code Explanation :

At first in the `onclick` of the `button`s, you should pass `this` key word so that you can retrieve the button element inside of your call back function:

```
<button onclick="getTrack(this)">get this track src</button>
```

After that inside of your `onclick` callback function, the argument `elm` is the button element which is clicked and we will convert it to a jquery element using `$(elm)` to use it's `siblings` function which return the button's siblings elements. Here we use `"audio"` selector because we just want to retrieve the `audio` sibling of the button and also `first()` is because the `siblings` function will return list of matched element while we just want the first element.

```
let $aud = $(elm).siblings( "audio" ).first();
```

So now `$aud` is the `audio` element associated with the pushed button and we should get it's `src` attribute using `attr` function.

```
console.log($aud.attr("src"));
```

Comment: i dont understund the cod but it works thank you bro

Comment: @salah, See my edit and I hope you will understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

`onclick` can take an argument representing the "click" event (like `onclick="getTrack(event)"`). Inside the function, that click event has a `.target` propery that you can use to reach into the DOM and get the button element itself. Then you can "walk" up the DOM tree and choose a different element, like:

```
function getTrack(event){
  const btn = event.target;
  const li = btn.parentElement;
  const audio = li.children[1];
  const src = audio.getAttribute("src");
  console.log(src);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use unique id for elements.Pass the element on function call and get the href attribute from it

```js
function getTrack(id)
{

console.log(id.getAttribute("src"))
}
```

```html
<ul id="playList">
  <li>
    <a href="audio/track1.mp3" >track1</a>
    <audio src="audio/track1.mp3" id="aud1"></audio>
    <button onclick="getTrack(aud1)">get this track src</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="audio/track2.mp3" >track2</a>
    <audio src="audio/track2.mp3" id="aud2"></audio>
    <button onclick="getTrack(aud2)">get this track src</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="audio/track3.mp3"  >track3</a>
    <audio src="audio/track3.mp3" id="aud3"></audio>
    <button onclick="getTrack(aud3)">get this track src</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery you can use [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) to grab the button's corresponding `audio` element, and get it's `src` value.

Here I've also removed the inline JS and used [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) after selecting the buttons from the DOM with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment/querySelectorAll) which is the modern way to code JS, and makes your markup leaner. I've used [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the `previousElementSibling` from the clicked element and relabeled it as "audio".

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#playList button');
[...buttons].forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', getTrack, false));

function getTrack() {
  const { previousElementSibling: audio } = this;
  console.log(audio.src);
}
```

```html
<ul id="playList">
  <li>
    <a href="audio/track1.mp3">track1</a>
    <audio src="audio/track1.mp3" id="aud"></audio>
    <button>get this track src</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="audio/track2.mp3">track2</a>
    <audio src="audio/track2.mp3" id="aud"></audio>
    <button>get this track src</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="audio/track3.mp3">track3</a>
    <audio src="audio/track3.mp3" id="aud"></audio>
    <button>get this track src</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```